# Why glTranslatef?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I just don't understand why in this case if I get rid of this stroke `gl.glTranslatef(0.0f,(float)Math.sin(mTransY), -3.0f);` square just not drawing? 
Full code here (and  ignore those cyrillic comments - i just wrote for myself what each func does )

*MainActivity class*

```
package opengl.tutorial.one;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                GLSurfaceView view = new GLSurfaceView(this);
                view.setRenderer(new SquareRenderer(true));
                setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

*Square class*

```
package opengl.tutorial.one;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10; //1
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;

public class Square {

    private FloatBuffer mFVertexBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer mColorBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer mIndexBuffer;

    public Square(){

        float vertices[] = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f,//0
            1.0f, -1.0f, //1
            -1.0f, 1.0f, //2
            1.0f, 1.0f  //3
        };//задали положение веришн квадрата по координатам

        byte maxColor=(byte)255;

        byte colors[] = //задали цвет веришнам
        {
            maxColor,maxColor, 0,maxColor,
            maxColor,maxColor, 0,maxColor,
            maxColor,maxColor, 0,maxColor,
            maxColor,maxColor, 0,maxColor,
        };

        byte indices[] = //порядок построения треугольников вершинами
        {
            0, 3, 1, //первый
            0, 2, 3  //второй
        };

        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4); //5
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        mFVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        mFVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        mFVertexBuffer.position(0);

        mColorBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length);
        mColorBuffer.put(colors);
        mColorBuffer.position(0);

        mIndexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
        mIndexBuffer.put(indices);
        mIndexBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl) //6
    {
        gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CW); //выводит полигон по заданной ориентации к экрану. CW - по часовой
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, mFVertexBuffer); //Установка массива для вершинных координат 
        gl.glColorPointer(4, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, mColorBuffer); //9
        gl.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 6,GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mIndexBuffer);
        gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CCW); //выводит полигон по заданной ориентации к экрану. СCW - против часовой
    }

}
```

*class SquareRenderer*

package opengl.tutorial.one;

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL10; //1
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;

import java.lang.Math;

public class SquareRenderer implements Renderer  {

    private boolean mTranslucentBackground;
    private Square mSquare;
    private float mTransY;
    private float mAngle;

    public SquareRenderer(boolean useTranslucentBackground)
    {
        mTranslucentBackground = useTranslucentBackground;//прозрачный фон
        mSquare = new Square(); //новый объект типа квадрат
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) //4
    {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //5
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); //6
        gl.glLoadIdentity(); //7
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f,(float)Math.sin(mTransY), -3.0f); //8
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); //9
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        mSquare.draw(gl); //10
        mTransY += 0f;
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) //11
    {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); //12
        float ratio = (float) width / height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); //13
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10); //14
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) //15
    {
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER); //16
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
        if (mTranslucentBackground) //18
        {

        }
        else
        {
            gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        }
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); //19
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH); //20
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST); //21
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole square is at z=0 plane. glTranslatef defines point of view 3.0 by z axis. Without this call, the point of view has z=0 coordinate, so you are looking at the square inside of the square itself.

Play with glTranslatef coordinates to see what happens. The best way to understand the meaning of every OpenGL function is to exclude/include it (well, you have already done this...) and to set different parameter values.

y parameter of glTranslatef gives rotation effect around y-axis.

Comment: Oh, now i get it! Should I use *gluLookAt* to be able to see square without this *glTranslatef* ?